# How can I open my extension's popup window programmatically in code?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

`chrome.action.openPopup()` doesn't work

```
Error in event handler: TypeError: chrome.action.openPopup is not a function
    at chrome-extension://bnkbabddbababkcladbpoakleneigmmi/js/background.js:71:19
```

Manifest file:

```
"action": {
        "default_popup": "html/popup.html",
        "default_title": "Popup",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "icons/icon-16.png",
            "32": "icons/icon-32.png",
            "48": "icons/icon-48.png",
            "128": "icons/icon-128.png"
        }
}
```

I want to open popup when I use contextmenus, I'm doing a summarizing extension, I would like to select the text, use contextmenus and paste the selected text into the open popup.

Comment: The documentation says it's only available for extensions installed via policies. You'll have to open a new window using chrome.windows.create or use chrome.sidePanel.